# How to deploy a SharePoint SPClaimProvider

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, people-picker, claim-provider

I am really struggling trying to figure out how to deploy an SPClaimProvider.

1. First, I have written a C# custom `SPClaimProvider` using [this example code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff604688(v=office.14)).  Assume that my code is the same as the sample.  I have a hard coded user store just for testing.
2. Then [according to this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-claims-provider-in-sharepoint), I need to create a `SPClaimProviderFeatureReceiver`, which I have done.  My code is almost exactly the same as [this sample](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-claims-provider-in-sharepoint#deploying-a-claims-provider-as-part-of-a-setup).
3. Now the documentation is really lacking.  In the same page, it says to create a Farm scoped feature.

I really don't know how to do this.  I have created a SharePoint 2019 "Add-in" project which has a Features and Package folder.  I have tried to add my code to the feature, right click the project and publish, which creates an app file.

I do not want to publish to an app store.  My SharePoint admin said to publish to a WSP file, but I don't know how to do that.  We are trying to use this claim provider in a SharePoint 2019 on-premise installation.

I had chosen (perhaps incorrectly) to do a SharePoint Add-in project type.  Here are the project types available in Visual Studio 2019:
[image]

Do I need to [set up a SharePoint / Visual Studio development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/set-up-a-general-development-environment-for-sharepoint) in order to get the correct project type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Full Trust Solution project, not an 'Add-in' project. The full trust solution compiles to a WSP, which you can then upload to the farm via `Add-SPSolution` and finally install it via `Install-SPSolution`.

You cannot publish full trust code to the app store.

--

You will need to build out a new SharePoint farm (single server is likely all you need) and install Visual Studio on it in order to develop a full trust solution. You can then use the 'SharePoint 2019 - Empty Project' project type.

From there, you can develop/debug your claims provider before creating a Release mode package which you will copy to a SharePoint server in your production farm for deployment.

Comment: What are the steps?

Comment: Hi Trevor, I do not see a *Full Trust Solution* project.  I edited the question and included the project types I have.  Do I want "Import Solution Package"?

Comment: See my edit... :)